# How to nest Redux Toolkit reducers for a single property

Tags: javascript, redux, architecture, refactoring, redux-toolkit

I'm migrating a codebase from vanilla Redux to Redux Toolkit. I'm trying to find a good way to nest reducers created with `createReducer` just for a single property.

Let's say I have a setup like the following contrived example with a `user` reducer and a `friends` reducer nested under it. The user can change their name, which only affects itself, and also add and remove their friends, which affects itself and its `friends` array property that is managed by the `friends` reducer.

```js
const CHANGE_NAME = "CHANGE_NAME";
const ADD_FRIEND = "ADD_FRIEND";
const REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS = "REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS";

const initialState = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  lastActivity: 0,
  friends: [],
};

const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_NAME: {
      const { newName, time } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        name: newName,
        lastActivity: time,
      };
    }
    case ADD_FRIEND:
    case REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS: {
      const { time } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        friends: friends(state.friends, action),
        lastActivity: time,
      };
    }
    default: {
      return {
        ...state,
        friends: friends(state.friends, action),
      };
    }
  }
};

const friends = (state = initialState.friends, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FRIEND: {
      const { newFriend } = action.payload;

      return [...state, newFriend];
    }
    case REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS: {
      return [];
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

To note:

- `friends` is necessarily correlated with `user`, so I had decided to nest it within its state slice.
- `user` manually calls the `friends` reducer to calculate the `friends` slice of state with possibly overlapping action types, and only for that one `friends` property.

I am now trying to refactor this with Redux Toolkit `createReducer`s. My first attempt was the following:

```js
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const CHANGE_NAME = "CHANGE_NAME";
const ADD_FRIEND = "ADD_FRIEND";
const REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS = "REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS";

const initialState = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  lastActivity: 0,
  friends: [],
};

const user = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(CHANGE_NAME, (state, action) => {
      const { newName, time } = action.payload;

      state.name = newName;
      state.lastActivity = time;
    })
    .addMatcher((action) => action.type === ADD_FRIEND || action.type === REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS),
    (state, action) => {
      const { time } = action.payload;
      state.lastActivity = time;
      state.friends = friends(state.friends, action);
    };
});

const friends = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(ADD_FRIEND, (state, action) => {
      const { newFriend } = action.payload;

      state.push(newFriend);
    })
    .addCase(REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS, () => []);
});
```

To note:

- The last matcher for the `user` reducer is the main focus here.
- The `friends` reducer now has two ways of modifying the state: "modifying" the state by pushing to it with `.push`, and returning a new empty state by directly returning `[]`.

In my intuition this would work as it appears to be the same logic. However, this only works for the `ADD_FRIEND` action, and does nothing or emits an error about simultaneously modifying state and returning a new state for the `REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS` action type.

This seems to be because the state being modified turns it to an ImmerJS `Proxy` object in the `user` reducer, but when it is passed to the `friends` reducer and it returns a state object directly instead of modifying it causing RTK to throw an error as it says you must only modify *or* return state, but not both. In the handler for `ADD_FRIEND` this is not an issue as it always modifies the state, the same as all the handlers in `user`.

As a hacky workaround I have manually checked whether the `friends` reducer returns a `Proxy` or a new state directly, and if it returns a new state then it sets it in the `user` reducer, but I am sure there is a better way:

```js
import { createReducer, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const user = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addMatcher((action) => action.type === ADD_FRIEND || action.type === REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS),
    (state, action) => {
      const { time } = action.payload;

      state.lastActivity = time;

      const result = friends(state.friends, action);

      let output;
      
      // If state has been returned directly this will error and we can set the state manually,
      // Else this will not error because a Proxy has been returned, and thus the state has been
      // set already by the sub-reducer.
      try {
        output = current(result);
      } catch (error) {
        output = result;
      }

      if (output) {
        state.progress = output;
      }
    };
});
```

My question is then how can I fix this so that I don't have to manually check the return type and can easily nest RTK reducers within each other, whether it be by restructuring my reducers or fixing the code logic?

Ideally I would still like to keep the `friends` reducer nested under the `user` reducer as that is how a lot of "vanilla" Redux code structures their state logic with many different reducers handling many different pieces of state, instead of them all being nested at the root-level with a single `combineReducers` call, but if there is a better and cleaner solution given I am fine with that too.

Thanks for any help, and sorry for the long post - just wanted to be as detailed as possible as other solutions online didn't seem to address this exact problem.

Comment: If you are still having problems after fixing the things I suggested then please post a CodeSandbox where you are having an error.  Here is mine where it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-brook-sqmz4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks for replying! You made me find out that the issue was that I was returning a new state from the user reducer by spreading it and setting the `friends` property in the object spread, then when `friends` modified the state ImmerJS produced an error as I was returning state from the `user` reducer as well as modifying it from the `friends` reducer at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my original `user` reducer code was reducer was returning a new state object by spreading the state and setting the `friends` property in that object spread. This produced an error from ImmerJS as it was returning a new value from the `user` reducer and was also modifying it in the `friends` reducer at the same time.

My posted code worked (with some modifications thanks to Linda), but to fix my original code (and I had not posted the version that produced errors - apologies) I had to change the following:

```js
.addMatcher(
  (action) =>
    action.type === ADD_FRIEND || action.type === REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS,
  (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    lastActivity: action.payload.time,
    friends: friends(state.friends, action)
  })
)
```

to:

```js
.addMatcher(
  (action) =>
    action.type === ADD_FRIEND || action.type === REMOVE_ALL_FRIENDS,
  (state, action) => {
    const { time } = action.payload;
    state.lastActivity = time;
    state.friends = friends(state.friends, action);
  }
)
```

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case it's easy to handle the `friends` property in the `user` reducer: `state.friends.push(newFriend)` or `state.friends = []`.  But there shouldn't be any issue with keeping it separate.

I did notice a few issues when trying to run your code:

- Using the `initialState` for the whole user as the initial state of `friends`, instead of `initialState.friends` or `[]`
- Unmatched parentheses in `addMatcher` around the `action.type` check
- Assigning to `state.name` instead of `state.username`

After fixing those I was not able to reproduce your issue. I am able to add and remove friends successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This could actually be a bug in Redux Toolkit. Could you please file an issue with a reproduction CodeSandbox over at out github issue tracker?